# The convergence of $\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$.

i) Determine the limit-function $f$.

ii) Does $f_n(x)$ converge uniformly to $f$?

For the first: We have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x^2+\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$,

because $\sqrt{*}$ is continuous.

But I was not able to proof ii). I am pretty sure that the convergence is uniformly, but I dont know how to prove this..:/

I am thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: Do you know what uniform convergence means?

Comment: What's the domain of $f$ ?

Comment: Note that $|\sqrt(a) - \sqrt(b)| \leq \sqrt(a - b)$ for all $a \leq b \leq 0$.

Comment: Take $||\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} - |x|  ||$ and prove that it is going to 0

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis That's pointwise convergence. Uniform convergence is stricter.

Comment: You must take the $sup|| f_n(x) - f(x) || \to 0$ and take the supremum with respect to x but the limit with respect to n . So this is what i have written , in more simple way. Pointwise convergence to the other hand is to take a steady $x$ and see where the $f_n(x) $ goes, leaving the n goes to $\inf$

Answer (score 5):

The definition for uniform converge is:

> $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N >0 , \forall n\geq N,  \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f_n(x) -f(x)| < \epsilon $

In this case: $f_n = \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}, f = |x|$

For $x \geq 0$, $$f_n(x) -f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} - x > x-x >0$$
$$f_n(x) -f(x) = \frac{1/n}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} + x } \leq \frac{1/n}{\sqrt{0^2+\frac{1}{n}} + 0 } = \sqrt{1/n} \leq \sqrt{1/N}$$

In other words,  $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R^+\cup \{0\}}}f_n(x) -f(x) = \sqrt{1/N}$

For $x \leq 0$, in same manner, $$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R^-\cup \{0\}}}f_n(x) -f(x) = \sqrt{1/N}$$

Let $\sqrt{1/N} = \epsilon$ So $|f_n(x) -f(x)|$ is well-bounded.

$\forall \epsilon >0,  N = 1/\epsilon^2$
satisfying uniform convergence.

How can I come up with such idea:

Firstly, I do the x>0 case:

$$ \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} - x < \epsilon \implies \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} <\epsilon+x \implies x^2+\frac{1}{n} < x^2+2\epsilon x+ \epsilon^2$$.

On the left hand side the item only independent of x is $\frac{1}{n}$. One the RHS, it is $\epsilon^2$

So I let $1/n = \epsilon^2$ and find such method.

Comment: In more simple way , (you don't need to separate $x\geq 0 $ and $ x\leq 0$)

In more simple way , (you don't need to separate $x\geq 0 $ and $ x\leq 0$)

$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} | f_n(x) - f(x) | =\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} | \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} - |x|\hspace{2mm}  | = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\Big| \frac{x^2+\frac{1}{n}-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} +\sqrt{x^2}}  \Big| = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\Big| \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} +\sqrt{x^2}}  \Big| \leq \Big| \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{0^2+\frac{1}{n}} +\sqrt{0^2}}  \Big| \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \to 0$$ as  $n \to \infty$
. 
.

Comment: I m pretty sure you understand the uniform convergence but is a big , very big mistake to firstly say $\forall x ...$ you can see to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence  below from the definition ... the "Notes" section
You must start with $\forall \epsilon > 0$ because in your way you write the pointwise convergence. If you don't want to confuse , you can say it 
in a simple way :
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists n_0 :   \forall n \geq n_0  \text{  apply  } \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(x) - f(x) | < \epsilon$$

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis if I stated the N and ϵ doesnt depends on x, was that right?

Comment: Zack_Ni : (I cant write @Za.... sorry) Then i suppose you are right. I 'm pretty sure you understanding ,your solution is obviously right , but if you write quantifiers (its very strict form)you must set each of them to the right position .

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed it.

Comment: Don't say sorry :D . I write with a kindness

Answer (score 0):

Using $\sqrt {a+b} \le \sqrt a + \sqrt b$ for $a,b\ge 0,$ we see that $\sqrt {x^2 + 1/n} \le |x| + \sqrt {1/n}.$ Thus, for any $n,$

$$0 \le \sqrt {x^2 + 1/n} - |x| \le \sqrt {1/n}$$

for all $x\in \mathbb R.$ This gives uniform convergence on $\mathbb R.$